# Mongodb freezing

Tags: mongodb, memory, cloud, freeze

I'm using MongoDB on a cloud server with 10GB of storage and 1GB RAM. After importing about 4.4 GB of data into a MongoDB database, whenever I type "mongo" on the commandline to test some queries, the server freezes.
Is there a cap on the memory resource allocation to MongoDB that I can remove? Or is it simply a matter of increasing RAM?

Comment: Have you actually run any queries before it freezes? MongoDB doesn't start grabbing memory into resident if you haven't performed any operations on it.

Comment: No, it freezes as soon as the mongo> prompt appears

Comment: Make sure that you have swap enabled. Many cloud hosters have it turned off.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB uses memory mapped files, which are allocated by the OS.  This means that there is no specific resource that you can free up to make more room for a Mongo console to run.

There are a couple of things to note about your environment.  Firstly, the amount of RAM you have for the amount of data you have loaded is on the small side.  MongoDB is going to try and keep as much of the working set in memory as it can, to avoid page faults as the disc seeks are a real killer for performance. Secondly, there will be some initial work going on when the data is loaded which could affect performance.

You can check out the Wiki page [Checking Server Memory Usage](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage) for information on how much memory Mongo is using up, and general information on the Memory Usage of Mongo.

Can you try and connect to the MongoD from another machine, so as to remove this burden from the DB Server?